# What is the stop condition of tracking

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When the tracking process is over, what makes it stop? I use waypoint_ Loader, in pure_pursuit Using dialog
I appreciate it if you have any idea.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380298/what-is-the-stop-condition-of-tracking/) by [liuliuliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70833/liuliuliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-06-17**:
I'm not sure I understand your question. Tracking is used to track the movement of objects.

**Comment by [liuliuliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70833/liuliuliu/) on 2021-06-17**:
Sorry, the words are not accurate. I want to know Stop condition of pure_ pursuit algorithm In autoware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`pure_pursuit` only controls lateral movement - not longitudinal - so it does not cause the vehicle to stop. `velocity_set` is a node which typically causes the vehicle to stop and the conditions depend on your parameter settings. However, in general, `velocity_set` looks for lidar points within a certain sphere around each waypoint. If the number of lidar points within that sphere exceeds a threshold (set in your parameter settings) then it reduces the velocity to 0 before that waypoint.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1